# android how to show progress dialog on snackBar?

Tags: android-asynctask, progressdialog, snackbar

Is there way to show progress dialog on snackBar while getting data from server for pagination inside AsyncTask.If is this possible then how to do this.Please give suggestions.

Comment: try this..https://github.com/tingyik90/snackprogressbar

Answer (score 20):

For new design library:

if you want to show progressBar in left side:

```
 Snackbar bar = Snackbar.make(root, R.string.data_updating, Snackbar.LENGTH_INDEFINITE);
        ViewGroup contentLay = (ViewGroup) bar.getView().findViewById(android.support.design.R.id.snackbar_text).getParent();
        ProgressBar item = new ProgressBar(context);
        contentLay.addView(item,0);
        bar.show();
```

or in right side:

```
 Snackbar bar = Snackbar.make(root, R.string.data_updating, Snackbar.LENGTH_INDEFINITE);
        ViewGroup contentLay = (ViewGroup) bar.getView().findViewById(android.support.design.R.id.snackbar_text).getParent();
        ProgressBar item = new ProgressBar(context);
        contentLay.addView(item);
        bar.show();
```

Comment: Its 2018 and if you are using Google's new material design then the id should be `com.google.android.material.R.id.snackbar_text`

Comment: Call `getParent()` twice: `bar.getView().findViewById(com.google.android.material.R.id.snackbar_text).getParent().getParent()`

Answer (score 8):

the easiest and the best approach would be this:

```
Snackbar bar = Snackbar.make(layout, "Somthing", Snackbar.LENGTH_INDEFINITE);
Snackbar.SnackbarLayout snack_view = bar.getView();
snack_view.addView(new ProgressBar(context));
bar.show();
```

SnackbarLayout `extends` LinearLayout, so you can add view as a child or customize it the way you want.

for example to change the style of the TextView inside SnackBar you can do this:

```
TextView tv = (TextView) bar.getView().findViewById(android.support.design.R.id.snackbar_text);
tv.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
tv.setTextSize(0, dimen[1] / 40);
tv.setTypeface(Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(),"fonts/font.otf"));
```

Comment: not sure if something changed in the API but bar.getView returns a View object and as you know you can't add children to a view.

Comment: Alberto M
yep, Api has been changed, now you just have to cast it to SnackbarLayout. everything else is the same.

Answer (score 3):

I've written a library that do just that. It also includes queue system. Try it out https://github.com/tingyik90/snackprogressbar

Answer (score 2):

### Kotlin 2021:

```
fun showLoadingSnackbar(){
    val snackbar: Snackbar = Snackbar.make(findViewById(R.id.rootlayoutid), "TEXT or RES", Snackbar.LENGTH_INDEFINITE)
    val viewGroup = snackbar.view.findViewById<View>(com.google.android.material.R.id.snackbar_text).parent as ViewGroup
    viewGroup.addView(ProgressBar(this))// Or Context if not in Activity
    snackbar.show()
}
```

If you want it on the left simply call `addView(ProgressBar(this),0)` instead as mentioned in the other answer

Edit: The answer has the progressbar at the top if the text is too long, so for it to be centered you can do this:

```
val snackbar: Snackbar = Snackbar.make(this, text, duration)
    val viewGroup = snackbar.view.findViewById<View>(com.google.android.material.R.id.snackbar_text).parent as ViewGroup
    viewGroup.addView(ProgressBar(context).also {
        it.layoutParams = ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT)
        it.foregroundGravity = Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL
    })
snackbar.show()
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you could style a custom progress dialog to look like a Snackbar, since snackbar doesn't prevent user interaction with GUI while loading.

Update:

Try this:

Create anim res file name it slide_in.xml and paste this:

```
<translate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:fromYDelta="50%p" android:toYDelta="0%p"
android:duration="@android:integer/config_longAnimTime"
/>
```

create another anim res file name it slide_out.xml:

```
<translate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:duration="@android:integer/config_longAnimTime"
android:fromYDelta="0%p"
android:toYDelta="100%p" />
```

now place process dialog style in style res:

```
<style name="CustomDialog" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Dialog">
    <item name="android:windowMinWidthMajor">100%</item>
    <item name="android:windowMinWidthMinor">100%</item>
    <item name="android:background">#323232</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">#FFFFFF</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:backgroundDimEnabled">true</item>
    <item name="android:alertDialogStyle">@style/customDialogStyle</item>
    <item name="android:windowAnimationStyle">@style/DialogAnimation</item>

</style>

<style name="customDialogStyle">
    <item name="android:bottomBright">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:bottomDark">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:bottomMedium">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:centerBright">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:centerDark">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:centerMedium">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:fullBright">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:fullDark">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:topBright">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:topDark">@android:color/transparent</item>
```

Place this for animation:

```
<style name="DialogAnimation">
    <item name="android:windowEnterAnimation">@anim/slide_in</item>
    <item name="android:windowExitAnimation">@anim/slide_out</item>
</style>
```

Now add you method:

```
public static ProgressDialog processSnackbar(Context context,String s){
    ProgressDialog pSnackbar = new ProgressDialog(context, R.style.CustomDialog) {
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

            ProgressBar progress = (ProgressBar) findViewById(android.R.id.progress);
            LinearLayout bodyLayout = (LinearLayout) progress.getParent();
            TextView messageView = (TextView) bodyLayout.getChildAt(1);

            messageView.setPadding(20,0,0,0);
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams llp =
                    (LinearLayout.LayoutParams) messageView.getLayoutParams();
            llp.width = 0;
            llp.weight = 1;


            bodyLayout.removeAllViews();
            bodyLayout.addView(messageView, llp);
            bodyLayout.addView(progress);
        }
    };
    pSnackbar.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);
    pSnackbar.setMessage(s);
    pSnackbar.getWindow().setGravity(Gravity.BOTTOM);
    pSnackbar.setCancelable(false);
    return pSnackbar;
}
```

Method Credit returns to @mike-m reference [Is it possible to alter progress dialog's message or spinner position?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35480018/is-it-possible-to-alter-progress-dialogs-message-or-spinner-position)

I am using this as well in my application take a look:

[image: snickersBar]

Comment: How can you do this with an ACTION?