# Is it possible to alter progress dialog's message or spinner position?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-alertdialog

I basically want to put message text before progress bar (spinner) in progress dialog in order to look like snackbar.

Comment: Do you mean `ProgressDialog`? And could you please be more specific as to what exactly you want? Are you saying you just want the animation and the text to switch places?

Comment: Yeah sorry I face a lot of typo errors, and yes that what I exactly want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There might be some easier way to do this that I'm not thinking of at the moment, but you could override the `ProgressDialog`'s `onCreate()` method, and fiddle with the layout programmatically. For example:

```
ProgressDialog pd = new ProgressDialog(this) {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        ProgressBar progress = (ProgressBar) findViewById(android.R.id.progress);
        LinearLayout bodyLayout = (LinearLayout) progress.getParent();
        TextView messageView = (TextView) bodyLayout.getChildAt(1);

        LinearLayout.LayoutParams llp =
            (LinearLayout.LayoutParams) messageView.getLayoutParams();
        llp.width = 0;
        llp.weight = 1;

        bodyLayout.removeAllViews();
        bodyLayout.addView(messageView, llp);
        bodyLayout.addView(progress);
    }
};

pd.setMessage("Testing...");
pd.show();
```

I had a quick look through the source versions, and I think this should work for pretty much all of 'em.